# Limit of median of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$. Assuming that $n$ is odd, find the pdf of the sample median (say $M_n$). Does the pdf of the r.v. $(M_n-EM_n)/\sqrt{var(M_n)}$ converge to a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

My work: I find $M_n\sim Beta(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2})$, $E M_n=1/2$, and $var(M_n)=\frac{1}{4(n+2)}$. I do not know use which theorem to solve the limit problem.

Comment: A suggestion: Maybe you can apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF of $M_n$ is
$$ \frac1{\beta(\tfrac{n+1}2,\tfrac{n+1}2)} x_+^{(n-1)/2} (1-x)_+^{(n-1)/2} $$
where $x_+$ is defined to be $x$ if $x > 0$, and zero otherwise.

So the PDF of $(M_n - EM_n)/\sqrt{\text{var}(M_n)}$ is
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{4(n+2)} \beta(\tfrac{n+1}2,\tfrac{n+1}2)} \left(\frac12 + \frac x{\sqrt{4(n+2)}}\right)_+^{(n-1)/2} \left(\frac12 - \frac x{\sqrt{4(n+2)}}\right)_+^{(n-1)/2} \\ = \frac1{2^{n-1}\sqrt{4(n+2)} \beta(\tfrac{n+1}2,\tfrac{n+1}2)} \left(1 - \frac {x^2}{n+2}\right)_+^{(n-1)/2} $$
As $n\to \infty$, and using Stirling's Formula, we see that this converges to
$$ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} .$$

Comment: This problem was one of the past mathematical statistic exam. I did not learn stirling's formula. Can you solve the problem using book statistic inference, George Casella?

Comment: I cannot think of another way to do this.  But Stirling's formula is quite straightforward https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation, and it works for the Gamma function as well as $n!$.